# How to maintain history changes in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, linq

I am using asp.net wth linq and my backend is mssql.

i want to keep history about ant changes happened in database.

please help me

table script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Band_Level](
    [band_level_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [band_level_name] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
    [description] [varchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
    [Display_name] [varchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
    [Sorting] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NULL,
    [modified_by] [int] NULL,
    [modified_date] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Band_Level] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
```

i want to show this history in .aspx page

Comment: changes on data or on schema ?

Comment: Which version of `SQL` are you using? If you're using `SQL 2008` there are some useful ideas in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875078/ways-to-maintain-data-history-in-sql-server-2008-database

Comment: This is an overly general question.  Have you tried anything?  Is there a direction you're thinking about taking? Doesn't seem like much due diligence before asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly then your Question is outside of the topic because if you want to keep track of what you've done in database that should be done programmatically Or with triggers by storing every thing on DUI(Delete,Update,Insert).