# Invoice database design

Tags: sql-server, database-design, invoice

The invoice database design, might look something like this...
http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/invoices_and_payments/index.htm

Now If the user decides to change/revise the product code/description

It will change the previous order and invoice produce code/description :(

What do you do? Copy the product code description to the invoice table instead?

Comment: What's wrong with storing the product codes/descriptions with the invoice? More specifically, I see them stored in `Invoice_Line_Items`, following the design the link points to.

Comment: duplication that waste resources, also unable to track what was changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You basically have two options:

- either you make your `Products` table "time-enabled" (also known as "temporal database"), e.g. you keep the "previous" state of your individual product in your table, and you give every entry a `ValidFrom / ValidTo` pair of dates. That way, if you change your product, you get a new entry, and the previous one remains untouched, referenced from those invoices that used it; only the `ValidTo` date for the product gets updated

or:

- you could copy the products (at least those bits you need for your invoice) to the invoice - that'll make sure you always know what the product looked like when you created the invoice - but this will cause lots of data duplication (not recommended)

See this other [Stackoverflow question on temporal databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800331/why-do-we-need-a-temporal-database) as another input, and also check out this article on Simple-Talk: [Database Design: A Point in Time Architecture](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/)

Comment: I never thought of it that way "temporary database" but I love it! Thanks alot!!!

Comment: @001: **temporal** - not temporary :-)