# How to Implement isolation level in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an employee table in which new records are inserting by procedure `dbo.ISP_InsertEmplyoeeDetails`. But at the same time another procedure `dbo.USP_UpdateEmplyoeeDetails` is updating the same records which are inserting in procedure `dbo.ISP_InsertEmployee` but not committed yet.

This creates data anomalies. I need to implement two scenarios here based on some the condition:

- Scenario 1: need to update the uncommitted insert data based on some condition
- Scenario 2: update will be blocked or on hold till insert operation committed its records

Comment: You cannot update an uncommitted record set in database. Why not check for a last update column before updating the record set, and if the last update column is not what you expect than it means someone has updated the records. Insert should be easy since you can rely on primary keys.

Comment: Thanks Peeyush ..Can you please help me out with query

Comment: There's not enough information here for me to help you out, but try searching for multiple client updating database, and you will find the typical approach for these scenario's. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616998/multiple-db-users-updating-at-the-same-time